# Unresponsive radio hardware switch

Tags: networking, wireless, hardware, wifi-hardware-switch

After trying to install kubuntu-desktop, dealing with conflicts, finally actually making a kubuntu clean install, I have a problem :
The wifi switch won't work. rfkill says my wifi card (broadcom for which I installed bcmwl-kernel-source) is hard-blocked (happened before), so I try to turn it on, and the switch just doesn't seem to want me to be able to turn on the wireless card. 
So now for the question: how can I turn the wifi on, knowing the hardware switch doesn't work? 
Thank you for your time and answers, 
ludwhe.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Actually fixed now, I'll answer solution for others with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself because I've fixed it unexpectedly: 
If you encounter this problem, try rebooting, enter BIOS Setup, restore default options. Worked for me.

Comment: You could mention a laptop model. This issue is specific to it.